# Implementing 3D Maps with MKMapView in iOS7

Tags: ios7, mkmapview

I've dropped an MKMapView into my project in Interface Builder and checked the ratio button for "3D Perspective".

But when I run the app, I'm unable to adjust the pitch using a two finger swipe, so it's appearing as though the 3D Perspective simply isn't functioning.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3D Perspective only works when the type is set to "Map". You can't pitch the view if it's type is Satellite or Hybrid.